# Syntax error when using function in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been trying to execute the following sql in postgres 9.6. But I get the error: `syntax error at or near "row"`. Which would be on the line where CREATE AND REPLACE FUNCTION starts.

I've made a sqlfiddle too if you prefer that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/48a30/1

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE input (
    id serial, certified boolean
);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tests_person (
  id serial, certified boolean
);

INSERT INTO input (id, certified) VALUES (DEFAULT, True), (DEFAULT, False), (DEFAULT, True), (DEFAULT, False), (DEFAULT, True), (DEFAULT, False);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_record(row input) RETURNS RECORD AS $$
    UPDATE "tests_person"
    SET certified=row.certified
    WHERE certified=row.certified
    RETURNING *
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: What is your goal actually ?

Comment: SQL SERVER! won't have to do that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`row` is a reserved word and you cannot use it as your parameter name.  Try this instead

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_record(_input input) RETURNS RECORD AS 
$$
    UPDATE tests_person
    SET certified=_input.certified
    WHERE certified=_input.certified
    RETURNING *
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: Thank you! Such a stupid mistake.. Now I know at least.